# NFQUEUE not being cleaned up properly

Tags: netfilter

I am creating an NFQUEUE with queue num 0 to receive the packet of the DNS Response and then I am changing the DNS response IP and push the changed packet again to the NFQUEUE.

Everything is working fine, But when my application is crashing, the Queue is bonded with the old PID and didn't clean up properly. So when I am running the application again, it's sometimes failing to create the new NFQUEUE and sometimes it succeeds (not sure exact scenario when it happens ).

Version Details:

- kernel version:4.13.12
- DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
- DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
- DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
- DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Can someone please help with the proper cleanup process.
As it is happening during the crash, I am not able to handle it.
`nfq_close()` and `nfq_destroy_queue()` are also unusable.